# How to evaluate Sum with Singularities?

Tags: summation, series-expansion, integral-equations, singularity

I derived equation of sum from the following problem,

$\int_{a}^{b}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} cos^n(x)dx$.

Using the following definitions,

$cos(x)=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$ and $(a+b)^n=\sum_{m=0}^{n}\binom {n}m a^{n-m}b^m$,

my solution to the above is,

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=0}^{n} \binom {n}m (-i)\frac{e^{i(n-2m)}}{n-2m} $.

However, Mathematica cannot evaluate this summation because of singularities. Either my derivation is incorrect although steps are valid or I must add conditionals to this summation evaluation (if it is valid way to do).  If my derivation is correct, how do I evaluate this summation,

```
Sum[Sum[-I*Binomial[n,m]*Exp[I*(n-2*m)/(n-2*m)),{m,0,n}],{n,0,100}]
```

Is there a way to avoid singularities? Like $n \neq 2m$

Comment: Your sum is a geometric series that is convergent for most real `x`and easily summable. I would compute that and then integrate.

Comment: `Sum[Cos[x]^n, {n, 0, \[Infinity]}, Assumptions -> x \[Element] Reals]` produces `1/(1 - Cos[x])`. If $\cos(x)=\pm1$, the series diverges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A direct approach to your problem works

```
sum = Sum[Cos[x]^n, {n, 0, ∞}]
(* 1/(1 - Cos[x]) *)


Integrate[sum, x]
(* -Cot[x/2] *)
```

Of course, the answer is only valid if the interval doesn't span a singularity (where `Cos[x]==1`)

Comment: If `Cos[x]==-1`, the series diverges so such points should be excluded too, when integrating.

Comment: Think of `sum = Sum[Cos[x]^n, {n, 0, \[Infinity]}, GenerateConditions -> True]` which results in `ConditionalExpression[1/(1 - Cos[x]), Abs[Cos[x]] < 1]`.